# Google Cloud Datastore: Does multitenancy have any benefit at all?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, datastore

Is datastore multitenancy bringing any benefit at all rather than logically separating the data of each tenant?

What's the difference of having a namespace per tenant rather than having data for all tenants i na single namespace?

Data is partitioned by projectId+ namespace right? This means that all the data within a single namespace will be located on the same disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is located based on Project ID. You can have multiple tenants, but they are still in the same place, so there are no performance benefits.

There only benefits are for ease of data management, because your data is now segregated. You can export / delete / query them separately easier.

Data in the same project is co-located, regardless of namespace / tenancy.